# Running apps in XCode, occasional error

Tags: xcode, gdb

Sometimes when I try to run an app on iPad, via XCode, I receive this error:

**not connected to remote gdb server**

Running application again will solve this error!

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to Quit Xcode. This happens all the time.

If it continues, delete the app off the device, clean the build folder  (THEN quit Xcode) and try again.

Comment: These are not solutions, they are escapes, present a solution.

Comment: You're asking for an idea, not a solution. I have an idea. I see it every day. It's just another Xcode bug.

Comment: There may be a solution though ;)